# MetalLB external load balancer on docker-desktop community edition on Windows 10 single-node Kubernetes Infrastructure

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop, metallb

I am trying to set up a metalLB external load balancer with the intention to access an nginx pod from outside the cluster using a publicly browseable IP address. I have follwed all the steps provided in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYiYIjlAgHY). I have managed to get the External-IP for service/nginx type:LoadBalancer, but when I try to browse the IP address, I get nothing and it says "This site can’t be reached".

[image: running kubectl get nodes -o wide shows]

[image]

I wonder whether is it even allowed on the docker-desktop win10 environment to access the k8s cluster resources from outside with a public IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Kuberntes provided by Docker Desktop is running in a VM and all network traffic is being NATed to a virtual machine. Even if you had everything properly configured on your network for using layer 2 and DHCP, your work or home router would not even know how to reach Docker which makes any services only available on the localhost.

To make it work you coud try using minikube with VirtualBox driver and set network interface to bridge, so that the minikube VM is visible to your router as a standalone instance and therefore arp requests can reach minikube.

Comment: Will it work with microK8s (single node k8s) on ubuntu based Linux OS?

Comment: I am not microk8s expert but I think it should. I have found in [microk8s documentation](https://microk8s.io/docs/addons) that there is metalLB addon.