# nginx ingress no controller service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rancher

Helo guys I'd like some help with an issue :
I'm using a kubernetes cluster that is provided to me by rancher (so I did not configured it)

but it has an nginx ingress controller :

```
 kubectl -n ingress-nginx get all -o wide
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/default-http-backend-598b7d7dbd-fgpns   1/1     Running   3          48d   192.168.121.64   pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-02   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-72d8s          1/1     Running   0          6d    172.34.10.123    pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-03   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-rn4fw          1/1     Running   0          6d    172.34.10.192    pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-01   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-v2m8b          1/1     Running   0          6d    172.34.10.173    pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-02   <none>           <none>

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
service/default-http-backend   ClusterIP   192.168.33.89   <none>        80/TCP    48d   app=default-http-backend

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE   CONTAINERS                 IMAGES                                                   SELECTOR
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-controller   3         3         3       3            3           <none>          48d   nginx-ingress-controller   rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.35.0-rancher1   app=ingress-nginx

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS             IMAGES                                                         SELECTOR
deployment.apps/default-http-backend   1/1     1            1           48d   default-http-backend   rancher/nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend:1.5-rancher1   app=default-http-backend

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS             IMAGES                                                         SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/default-http-backend-598b7d7dbd   1         1         1       48d   default-http-backend   rancher/nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend:1.5-rancher1   app=default-http-backend,pod-template-hash=598b7d7dbd
```

and as I'm watching a video tutorial ( [[ Kube 59.1 ] Nginx Ingress in Kubernetes Revisited](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnOZwxvxfnA)) **I noticed that he when he display all like me alongside the default backen svc in the ingress namespace he also has an "ingress-controller svc of type load balancer" and I don't, so how can I rectify that ?**
thank you for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to make it work , the nginx that was on my rancher was deployed from the rancher app catalogue, and the field "deploy a service" was set to false, so I upgraded it and put the field to true and it deployed me the load balancing service so now it's working fine.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx Ingress in Kubernetes Revisited 3:25](https://youtu.be/KnOZwxvxfnA?t=205) --> he sais that `nginx-ingress-controller` of type `LoadBalancer` goes from [**Metallb**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985098/no-externalip-showing-in-kubernetes-nodes/65991935#65991935). That means he running on-prem cluster, not in cloud. You can install the same using kubeadm

MetalLB makes LoadBalancer services:
https://metallb.universe.tf/

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers
> (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare metal clusters. The
> implementations of Network LB that Kubernetes does ship with are all
> glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…).
> If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…),
> LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when
> created.
>
> Bare metal cluster operators are left with two lesser tools to bring
> user traffic into their clusters, “NodePort” and “externalIPs”
> services. Both of these options have significant downsides for
> production use, which makes bare metal clusters second class citizens
> in the Kubernetes ecosystem.
>
> MetalLB aims to redress this imbalance by offering a Network LB
> implementation that integrates with standard network equipment, so
> that external services on bare metal clusters also “just work” as much
> as possible.

Comment: Hello yes But in my case I have a loadbalancer provided as I'm on the cloud (Openstack). Thank you